# Change Canvas to JFrame

Tags: java, swing, canvas, jframe

I want to change extend `Canvas` to `JFrame`. But why does my program not run? Command prompt reports:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.langIllegalArgumentException: 
  adding a window to a container 
  at java.awt.Container.chekNotAWindow(Container.java:483)" and so many more
```

Here is my code:

```
  class Layar extends Canvas implements Runnable,KeyListener
\\ init
    Layar()
    {
        super();
        try{
//adding a picture
            }
        catch(Exception e){}

    new Thread(this).start();
    addKeyListener(this);
    }
    public void update(Graphics g)
    {
        paint(g);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g)
    {
        g.drawImage(img,x_back,y_back+200,null);//background

//key listener

    public void run()
    {
        //try catch
}


public class stage2
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {


        JFrame window = new JFrame("aaaa");
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        window.setLocation(50,50);
        window.setSize(700,700);
        window.setResizable(false);
        window.add(new Layar());
        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Essentially, a window (or frame in this case) can't be added to another window.

Instead of using

```
JFrame window = new JFrame("aaaa");
```

Use

```
Layar window = new Layar();
```

Once you have changed the `Layar` to extend from `JFrame`.

Having said that.  Personally, you would better to simple extend from `JPanel` and continue adding `Layar` to the frame you created.  You will get better performance from custom painting then if you tried extending from a top level container.

You might also want to take a look at [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/), as you should be overriding `paintComponent` of Swing components rather then `paint`